# Java: Question about data representation

Tags: java

I need to parse 70mb data with Java and I've currently a xml document (1-level, no children), where each document has multiple fields.

I was wondering if I should replace it with a simpler text file in which each row is a doc, and the fields are comma separated.

Is this going to significantly improve performances ? And what if the I had, for instance, 4GB data instead ?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose XML in the first place?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Not really.

Comment: @user: Then if there's no pressing reason to use XML (e.g. you're not generating/parsing it with existing tools, and you have a suitable CSV-processing library), then don't use it.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Too late, I need to convert now, or not ?

Comment: @user680406: converting to FastInfoSet may prove *very* helpful to you while staying XML.  Of course the very fact that APIs like fastinfoset exists show how horribly bloated XML is but, hey, at least it solved the encoding, CR/Linefeed, spaces-vs-tab, issues etc.  In addition to that it validates etc.  So, yup, XML is one heck of a bloated 'text' format overused and overabused but it does have some merit.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be more efficient to use the text file than the XML file if you ever get to a point where you can't fit the whole data set into memory at once. at that point, being able to parse the text file line by line would be better than the XML approach <strike>(which I believe loads the whole file into memory).</strike>
According to a Robin Green XML only parses the whole file at once if you use DOM - SAX parsing streams.

There are other ways to persist data like this:
**[Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)**
Can this data be represented in a database? Java has easy support for most database systems, and you just have to install the right libraries to do so.

**[Java Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)**
An alternative is the java properties system. This lets you put all your data on a file and then load them back and java parses the file when loading it.

Comment: That's not correct - XML parsing only reads the whole file in one go if you use DOM - SAX parsing streams it.